# Django how to create object has foreignkey in views.py?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I've wrote this code:

***views.py***

```
    if not null:
            Address.objects.create(user = request.user,first_name = ad,last_name = soyad,address_title = baslik,address = adres,postalcode = posta,tel = gsm,il_ilce = Ilce.objects.get(il_id__il = sehir,ilce = ilce))
```

***models.py***

```
class Il(models.Model):
    il = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False,null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.il)

class Ilce(models.Model):
    ilce = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False,null=False)
    il_id = models.ForeignKey(Il,blank=False,null=False,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ilce)

class Address(models.Model):
    
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False,null=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address_title = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=False,null=False,default="Adres")
    address = models.TextField(max_length=255,blank=False,null=False)
    il_ilce = models.ForeignKey(Ilce,blank=False,null=False,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    postalcode = models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=False,null=False)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=11,blank=False,null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + '-' + str(self.address_title)
```

**but I'm getting this error:**

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Users_address_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

I don't want the code to create a new user object I want it to create a new address object only.

Comment: what is the value of `null`?

Comment: it's boolean @AnkitTiwari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`I don't want the code to create a new user object I want it to create a new address object only.`* - You've used **OneToOneField** in your **Address** model which means each user will have one address associated with it if you try to create one more then it will raise given exception *`duplicate key value violates unique constraint "Users_address_user_id_key"`* so to solve this you can use 
[**`update_or_create(...)`** [Djnago-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) or If you want to use multiple address against one use then you've to change **OneToOneFiled** to **ForeignKey**.